# R Shiny & Papaya (Medical Imaging Tool)

Tags: r, shiny

I am having trouble rendering the papayaWidget on Shiny, it just shows a blank page, you will find my session on this link and below the code I am using:

robertoromo-sessioninfo.txt

code:

```
library(kirby21.t1)
library(papayaWidget)
library(neurobase)

outdir = tempdir()
download_t1_data(outdir = outdir)

fname = kirby21.t1::get_t1_filenames(outdir = outdir)
fname = fname[3]

ui <- shinyUI(
fluidPage(
papayaOutput("test")
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$test<-renderPapaya({

img = readnii(fname)

print(img)
papaya(img)
})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

session info:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.2.0        kirby21.t1_1.7.0   neurobase_1.27.6   oro.nifti_0.9.1    papayaWidget_0.5.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0         later_0.8.0        git2r_0.24.0       compiler_3.5.2     shinyjs_1.0       
 [6] R.methodsS3_1.7.1  R.utils_2.8.0      prettyunits_1.0.2  base64enc_0.1-3    bitops_1.0-6      
[11] remotes_2.0.2      tools_3.5.2        testthat_2.0.1     digest_0.6.18      pkgbuild_1.0.2    
[16] pkgload_1.0.2      jsonlite_1.6       memoise_1.1.0      rlang_0.3.1        RNifti_0.10.0     
[21] cli_1.1.0          rstudioapi_0.9.0   curl_3.3           yaml_2.2.0         withr_2.1.2       
[26] desc_1.2.0         fs_1.2.6           htmlwidgets_1.3    devtools_2.0.2     DT_0.5.2          
[31] rprojroot_1.3-2    glue_1.3.0         R6_2.4.0           processx_3.2.1     sessioninfo_1.1.1 
[36] callr_3.1.1        magrittr_1.5       promises_1.0.1     matrixStats_0.54.0 splines_3.5.2     
[41] backports_1.1.3    ps_1.3.0           htmltools_0.3.6    usethis_1.4.0      assertthat_0.2.1  
[46] abind_1.4-5        xtable_1.8-3       mime_0.6           kirby21.base_1.7.0 httpuv_1.4.5.1    
[51] crayon_1.3.4       R.oo_1.22.0
```

Comment: *"find my session on this link"* ... what link?

Comment: Does it work outside shiny ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it does work outside shiny...

Comment: @r2evans session info added in edited comment.. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well, it seems to be the way you wrote `server()` which is incorrect. `server()` is a *function* so it works with the arguments passed to it (here: `input`,`output` and `session`). If you want to take `fname` into account, it shall be passed to an argument, as:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session, fname = fname) {

output$test<-renderPapaya({
  img = readnii(fname)
  print(img)
  papaya(img)
})

}
```

Another way to do it is to generate `fname` in the first lines of `server()` which I would recommend if `fname` is not to be used elsewhere in the code. A third alternative could be to write a function `renderPapayaCustom()` taking into account the generation of `fname`.

Comment: Download a dicom image from here [link](https://barre.nom.fr/medical/samples/) and then re run the shinyapp pointing the papaya function to the downloaded image. Same result a blank shinyapp. You can verify running the papaya function outside shiny with this downloaded image and it will run succesfully